# Explain part of equation with boxed braces

Tags: beamer, equations

I want to reproduce the following (for beamer):

[image]

I know that something similar is possible with `$\underbrace$`.
Do you know how to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses tikz to draw the bubble.  The bubble is included in the alignment rather than being overlaid.

If you plan on doing this a lot, you might try finding or creating a tikz "shape."

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathstyle}% for \currentmathstyle
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mymathbox}[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(temp.base)]{%
    \node(temp){$\m@th\currentmathstyle#1$};
    \draw (temp.south)+(2pt,0pt) -- +(0pt,-1ex) -- +(-2pt,0pt)% all offsets from (temp.south)
      [rounded corners] -- (temp.south west) -- (temp.north west) -- (temp.north east) -- (temp.south east)
      [sharp corners] -- cycle;
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \mymathbox{\frac{d}{dt}I(t)} = \frac{d}{dt}I(t)
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Very kind I have delete my last question. Excuse me and I upvote your answer.